# Accidental "Select all" in AWS console?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I can't possibly be the only person who has experienced what happens when you accidentally press ctrl-A in the AWS console website outside the scope of a textbox.  You cannot unselect anything until you do a refresh.  All text on the webpage will be highlighted and there is no where you can click to reset it.  Has anyone else experienced this?  I probably waste 2-4 minutes per day on this which means I have probably wasted almost an entire day of my life by now.

Comment: just click or double click one or time on the empty area of the page and it should be unselect, you do need to refresh the page. and the problem seems more related to the browser I think

Comment: yea that definitely doesn't work in chrome.  The worst is the SQS console.